# facebook share button not functioning

Tags: facebook, share

I am trying to add a Facebook share on my site and to check whether users share or not. Below is my code.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<input type="button"
  onclick="share_me(); return false;"
  value="Share"
/>
```

javascript:

```
FB.init({appId:365897140152061 ,status: true, cookie: true});
function share_me() {

FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  app_id: '365897140152061',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference documentation',
  description: 'Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.',
  message: 'thanks for visting'
},
function(response){
  if(response && response.post_id) {
    self.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
  }
  else {
    self.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
  }
});
}
```

When I share I get a message that an error occurred: Please try again later. How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: Try adding he parameter `show_error` with value `true` to your FB.ui parameters – that should give you a more detailed explanation on the error. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Do I need to live my app in order to use this function? because I am still in a testing mode before i proceed my development. thanks a lot for your reply..

Comment: Should be possible to use the dialog when the app is still in sandbox mode, AFAIK – if the user you’re testing with is admin or test user for this app.

Comment: okok thanks  a lot =) will look through it again..

Comment: i got this error and trying to solve but seems to be no luck.

API Error Code: 191

API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application

Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.